How can I fetch a decorator using a rest call for use with sitemesh 3
I want to decorate documents with a header and footer fetched from another site. The decorator fetched will vary based on info in the HttpServletRequest (locale and the like). How do I get sitemesh to fetch the decorator from another application rather than the path?
I can implement my own implementation of ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter and do the rest call myself but how do I get the payload to be processed by sitemesh? I.e
public class CustomSiteMeshFilter extends ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException{
        String html = client.fetchDecorator(httpRequest)
        // use fetched decorator
    }

Are there any other solutions?
